# Laravel 5: Updating Multiple Records

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I have a **Simple Todo App**, that doesn't persist the update of multiple records at once. The client version works properly here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVVpyN

Everytime I make an action, I fire a http request to my laravel API to persist the data. But I have trouble with my **completeAll method**.

Whenever I click the **Complete All** button, I execute the **completeAll method**:

```
completeAll: function () {
    var tasks = [];
    var taskIds = [];

    this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(function (task) {
        task.completed = true;
        tasks.push(task);
        taskIds.push(task.id);
        return task.completed;
    });

    this.$http.put('api/tasks/' + taskIds, { tasks: tasks });
},
```

Here I send a request to an URL that might look like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/1,3,8,4
```

And together with it, I send the **tasks object**. This is the request payload from chrome developer tools:

```
{tasks: [{id: 1, body: "One", completed: true, created_at: "2015-09-09 08:36:38",…},…]}
```

**Then** on the serverside I have an **update function** in my **TasksController** that looks like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // gives ["1", "2", "3"] instead of "1,2,3" a
    $taskIds = explode(",", $id);

    // what happens if I update more than one task at once
    // ** PROBLEMATIC SECTION **
    if (count($taskIds) > 1) {
        $tasks = Task::whereIn('id', $taskIds)->get()->toArray();
        $newTasks = Input::get('tasks');

        var_dump($tasks);
        var_dump($newTasks);

        /** This Line does not Work **/
        Task::whereIn('id', $taskIds)->update(Input::get('tasks'));

        return 'update more than one task at once';
    }

    // what happens if I update only one task
    Task::where('id', $id)->update(Input::all());

    return 'update exactly one task';
}
```

The above **$tasks** and **$newTasks** variable **var_dump** the same, because I use the **toArray()** method on the **$tasks** variable.

But when I try to update the tasks I get this error:

```
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

Not sure why. Since in my understanding **Task::whereIn('id', $taskIds)** is an object and not a string.

**Alternative routes that I tried so far**

1. Using a foreach/for loop, to loop through the $tasks array, which I couldn't make to work, because I had also to loop through the $newTasks array to assign them, like this:

   foreach ($tasks as $task) {
       for ($i=0; $i < count($taskIds); $i++) { 
           Task::where('id', $task->id)->update($newTasks[$i])
       }
   }
2. Creating another endpoint on my API to just complete every task, to an URL like this:

   http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/complete-all

And then executing a **completeAll** method on my TasksController, where I set each task to completed. But I couldn't make it work, because I got a

```
Method not allowed exception
```

Not sure why, but I figured it is better to use my original method with an API like this:

```
api/tasks/1,2,50,1,3
```

Because it was suggested here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/vuejs-delete-multiple-tasks-each-task-one-request

---

Please advice on my original attempt to help me make this simple TodoApp work.

Alternatively, if it is for the better, please help me make the foreach/for loop work. Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

According to an answer, it was suggested to follow point 2 from above and create an additional endpoint.

These are my routes:

[image]

I use a post method to the url:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/complete-all
```

Executed from my app.js throught this:

```
this.$http.post('api/tasks/complete-all');
```

And this is my adapted TasksController:

```
public function completeAll(Request $request)
{
    $tasks = Task::where('completed', false)->get();

    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
       Task::where('id', $task->id)->update(['completed' => true]);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'All tasks completed']);
}
```

The app persists the data now correctly, but it troubles me, that I am not really updating anything from the clientside. I am just executing serverside code, because I am not really passing any query.

How would I solve the problem, using an URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/1,23,43,5
```

Thanks

Comment: hi, it seems ur explaination of the problem is too broad, what do you mean by persisting data? please also explain on the parameters in your url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel CRUD methods expect on a single resource. As such, sending several resources to `update` at does not follow this requirement.

While you could update the `update` method, I would encourage you to create a `completeTasks` or `completeAll` method that operates on several resources. You could pass multiple resources in the request body.

To do this, you need to:

- Add a [Route](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-parameters)
- Parse the request data for Todo ids (like you `for` loop)
- Call `update` on the database (`Task::whereIn('id', $taskIds)->update()`)

Comment: Hi Jason, I did not understand your 2nd paragraph, what do you mean by: "You could pass mutiple resources in the request body". Also I Edited the post above to reflect your suggestions. It would be nice if you could have a look, because I didn't parsed any reqeust data to use a foreach loop to persist the data. Also I feel I didn't got my question answered, regarding a solution of an http request to an URL like this: http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/12,2,4,5

Comment: I went with the solution, to add two additional endpoints to my api, "complete-all" and "clear-completed", which I access through a simple post request. I then let the backend do the work (f.e. completing the tasks). You think this is the way to go? I kind of feel, that this solution is weird, because I don't actually pass any data of my tasks through my request to the server. I just execute some code on the server. You think this is perfectly ok, since I don't even use the $taskIds you mentioned.

Comment: I understand the feeling, but I think it's fine. The only edge case to consider is if the tasks can be created concurrently. In which case, you could complete a new task when completing all.

Comment: Though I am not happy witht he solution, I marked your answer as correct. Thank you for your assistance.